# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, google-maps, swift3

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        // 1
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // 2
        let correctedAddress:String! = self.searchResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false")


     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            // 3
            do {
                if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any],
                    let results = jsonObject["results"] as? [[String:Any]], !results.isEmpty,
                    let geometry = results[0]["geometry"] as? [String:Any],
                    let location = geometry["location"] as? [String:Double],
                    let lat = location["lat"], let lng = location["lng"] {

                    print("lat: \(lat) - lng: \(lng)")
                }




            }catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        })
        // 5
        task.resume()
    }
```

The image shows the error I am receiving after I run the app and search a location and click on it to display on the map.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want help, you need to post a [mcve] of the code you have tried.

Comment: What's the actual value of `url` by the time you call `dataTask`?

Comment: Avoid force unwrapping. It just causes crashes like this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your URL is creating a crash. It may be your URL is nil after unwrapping.  Try to use the below code if it works for you

```
let valueAtIndex = self.searchResults![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)
guard let correctedAddress = valueAtIndex else { return }
let adrString:String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false"
let url:URL = URL(string: adrString)!
```

Comment: How does this fix the issue? You are still force-unwrapping the URL.

Comment: Code shared by Austin will give nil URL after concatenation.

Comment: He is force unwrapping a nil URL because of which getting a crash. I have just fixed concatenation problem

Comment: But you are still force unwrapping the URL. Your code can also crash with the same error if `adrString` isn't a valid URL.

Comment: This resolves the error but I am a bit lost on how to not force unwrap it. The only thing that this doesn't resolve it my execution of the place mark when select the address from the autocomplete method. This was all working prior to Xcode 3.0. If there are any suggestions please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue, you could try replacing `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)` with `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)`

I'm not sure if there is a particular character in your query that's being rejected, but I had a similar issue as yours, and the `urlQueryAllowed` or `urlPathAllowed` character sets are there exactly to avoid that kind of issue